# How to shorten the output of an Association

Tags: performance-tuning, output-formatting, associations

I'm writing a function that steps through a parameter and returns the outputs of `NDSolve` to make crude bifurcation diagrams.  It seems like an `Association` would be a good data structure to return the results, but it takes way too long to make the fancy summary boxes for `InterpolatingFunctions` if you omit a semicolon to suppress output.

For example, I return from the function sometime like:

```
res = Association @@ Table[
  k -> NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]/k) - n[t] p[t]/(n[t] + 1), 
     p'[t] == n[t] p[t]/(n[t] + 1) - 0.2 p[t], n[0] == k, 
     p[0] == 0.1}, {n, p}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]]
, {k, 1, 4, 0.1}]
```

which takes 2.5 seconds to run, but only 0.05 second with a semicolon to suppress output.  Obviously, it's worse with a smaller step size.

Question: is there someway to shorten the results but keep them useable as an `Association`?  I've tried wrapping the whole output in `Short` and `Iconize`, but they aren't actually useable.  I've also considered making a new data structure with its own summary box, but I like that you can use `Map` with an `Association`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps something like:

```
ds = Dataset[Map[KeyMap[ToString]@*Association]@(Association @@ 
      Table[ToString @ k -> 
        NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]/k) - n[t] p[t]/(n[t] + 1), 
           p'[t] == n[t] p[t]/(n[t] + 1) - 0.2 p[t], n[0] == k, 
           p[0] == 0.1}, {n, p}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]], {k, 1, 4, 0.1}]), 
   MaxItems -> {3, 2}];
```

---

```
ds
```

[image]

```
ds["2.1"]
```

[image]

```
ds["2.1", "n"] /@ {2, .3, 5}
```

> ```
>  {1.98668, 2.08107, 1.60715}
> ```

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[Values[Normal[ds["1.2"]]]@t], {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotLabel -> "1.2", PlotLegends -> {"n", "p"}]
```

[image]

```
ds[{"1.", "1.4", "2.1"} /* 
   Map[Plot[Evaluate@ Through[Values[#][t]], {t, 0, 100}] &], 
{"n", "p"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting!  I'll dig into `Dataset` to see if I can tweak the aesthetics.

Comment: You might find this blog very useful: [New 12.1 Dataset Interactive Controls and Formatting Options](https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/06/23/new-12-1-dataset-interactive-controls-formatting-options/)